# explode function isn't retaining order but putting words into alphabetical order within the array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a variable with some various phrases/words in there, these are all separated by a comma. They are currently in the correct order within this variable.

However when I use

```
<?php 
  explode(",", $variable)
?>
```

The result when I loop through this array one by one and print out these words into a list is that they are in alphabetical order.

So my question is how do I retain this order.

The loop is as follows

```
 <?php
    if(!empty($variable)) {
      print '<ul>';
      foreach($variable as $key=>$value) {
        print '<li>- '.$value.' ' . '</li>';
      }
      print '</ul>';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't describe your code, post it!

Comment: `explode(',', $variable)` is the proper syntax... Please supply us with the complete source and an example string

Comment: explode will not sort an array. We need to see the full code to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Where is your *assignment*? From what you wrote it seems you might think that explode directly changes the given string. This is not the case, you'll need to assign or use the return value. `$variable` will not be changed.

Comment: This was an issue with the loop as I tried it with a for loop and the order was retained. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

explode doesn't change the order of the string elements 
check the result of this

```
<?php

$arr = explode(",", $variable);
foreach($arr as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
```

Comment: why not simply write `print_r($arr);` :)

Answer (score 0):

Explode doesnot change the order of the splitted words.

This if you explode the string `stack overflow user` by space,

the array will have:

```
stack
overflow
user
```

So, no need to think upon it.

```
$arr = explode(",", $variable);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Will simply work.